# Can burned DVD-R be changed

Tags: windows, dvd-burning

If a DVD-R+ oder DVD-R- is burned and finalized can it be changed? E. g. can a software be added?

An example is if a burned DVD-R is inserted in a computer which has a virus. Would it be possible that the virus is somehow transferred to the disk? 
If you try to add data to such a disk using Windows or Nero it is not working. But is it really a hardware issue - or is Windows "seeing" that it is DVD-R and preventing addition of the data to those disks? In this case a virus could ignore the Windows locking of the dvd-r?

Comment: @barbara I remember seeing an answer on here that says yes. I can't seem to find it though. I think it involved overwriting/nullifying some file system data, which results in lost space, but it seemed possible. I believe the jist was ignore the old file structure and make a new one.

Answer (score 2):

A finalized disc can't have data added. Before then data can be added either in the current open session if it hasn't been closed yet or in a new session if the disc hasn't been finalized.

From Microsoft Windows [some points](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-vista/close-or-finalize-a-cd-or-dvd) to consider/remember:

- After you close a disc session, you can still add additional files to
  the disc, but you must close each additional session to be able to
  use the disc on another computer.
- If you remove a disc from your computer without closing the disc
  session, you can close it at a later time. Just return it to the
  computer's disc burner and follow the steps above to close the
  session.
- Some programs might finalize your disc instead of closing the current
  session. You can't add any additional files to a disc that has been
  finalized.

Answer (score 0):

> if a burned DVD-R is inserted in a computer which has a virus. Would it be possible that the virus is somehow transfered to the disk?

No. Because the data can't be placed on the DVD unless its burned onto the disc with burning software.

> If you try to add data to such a disk using Windows or Nero it is not
>   working.

The is probably due to your CD/DVD rom or the software.

> But is it really a hardware issue - or is Windows "seeing" that it is
>   DVD-R and preventing addition of the data to those disks? In this case
>   a virus could ignore the Windows locking of the dvd-r? Thanks for you
>   opinions

im not really sure why you keep asking about dvd-r and dvd+r. Your first issue is seeing if your dvd rom burns anything to start with.

Comment: I would agree with all of this except for the first point. Viruses can certainly make their way onto a disk if they are written to infect the burning software. However unlikely, not impossible.

Comment: The final point: DVD-ROM drives will NOT be able to burn DVD discs of any type :o) I assume you mean DVD-RW...